# How to undo the effect of command "php artisan config:cache"?

Tags: php, laravel, configuration

I (by mistake) run the command **php artisan config:cache** in my local development setup, due to which all the calls(from my controllers) to the variables defined in ***.env*** file (like **$_ENV['APP_ENV']**, **$_ENV['ELS_INDEX']**, etc) are resulting in following errors :

> ErrorException in MainController.php line 470 ***<---- This is the line where .env variable is called***
>   Undefined index: APP_ENV

This is the link of  : [Configuration Caching](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/configuration#configuration-caching)

Please help me rectify this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Either run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

or remove the file `/bootstrap/cache/config.php` from your Laravel project.

(`php artisan config:cache` creates `/bootstrap/cache/config.php`)

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue, but why was config.php interfering with .env variables ?

Comment: Than you kerbholz - you saved me hours :-) .
@apprentice to answer your question, this documentation [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#configuration-caching) made sense to me, to some degree it addresses your question above.

Comment: after config:clear it's good to run again php artisan config:cache

Comment: @MHFuad True for production sites. I wouldn't recommend caching your config on dev/local environments if you need to adjust settings a lot

Comment: @MHFuad And `php artisan config:cache` already clears the configuration cache beforehand

Comment: Did AI write that answer? fyi:Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable –