# How to clear cache for database settings in Laravel 8?

Tags: database, laravel, caching

I have deployed my project on my webserver.  The .env contains the right settings for the web database but for some reason Laravel still try to connect to localhost.

The problem is that if I use any of the php artisan xxx:clear, it gives the same error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' ...

So I can I force Laravel 8 to clear the cache (as I guess this is the problem) and read the correct credentials in the .env file?

Comment: you need to clear  `php artisan config:clear` for clear env data

Comment: you can set db credential into  `config > databse.php` and  into the `bootstrap` folder, probably you will find a `cache` folder .. delete `cache` folder .... I think it will be okay..

Comment: @نور the cache folder is created again as well for older version and in newer version the path of cache folder is changed & is placed in vendor

Comment: try this command:- php artisan optimize

Comment: @bhucho  for removing current cache , I suggest to delete... I faced similar problem before..  actually it's worked for me...what is the issue ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54214306/how-to-undo-the-effect-of-command-php-artisan-configcache/54214517#54214517

Comment: php artisan config:clear and php artisan optimize give the same error BUT removing the content of the cache folder in bootstrap solved the problem.  Then I could run the optimize & clear cache!  Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Optimize command still works like champ Try

```
php artisan optimize
```

It will clear

1. Configuration cache
2. Route cache
3. Files cache

Answer (score 5):

hey you can use these commands

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

took me 3 hours to find out that my original env file is in another folder, and i opened "backup" folder in my code :D